# from sys import argv script, filename = argv, "testfile" txt = open("testfile","r"

Tags: python, python-2.7

am learning python the hard way by zedd shaw and anytime i try to read files, it keeps giving me error that no such file or directory exist, even after the file exist a

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv, "testfile"
txt = open("testfile","r")          

from sys import argv
script, filename = argv, "testfile"
txt = open("testfile","r")
```

> IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 from sys import argv
>         2 script, filename = argv, "testfile"
>   ----> 3 txt = open("testfile","r")
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testfile'

Comment: wild guess: `testfile` doesn't exist in the current directory

Comment: i later figured out what the problem was

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows you should configure your folder to show the known extensions in your filebrowser so you have the current naming.

here is a link to explain how to do it : https://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-file-extensions-in-windows

if the naming of your file was good you can use absolute path safely with :

```
import os
current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) # Absolute directory of the current python file
filename = "testfile.txt"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, filename)
```

Comment: yeah thanks alot i now discover where the error came from, thumbs up bro. appreciate @emmanuel ruaud

Comment: yeah thanks alot i now discover where the error came from, thumbs up bro. appreciate @emmanuel ruaud

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this way to access files, but in general, doing it that way you need to have the file in the folder your script is in and you need a file extension like .txt or .docx, you do not have an extension so it is looking for a file, not a text file.

Comment: yeah i tried that out and it worked, thanks alot , appreciate

Comment: Don't worry about it. I made that mistakes loads of times, not adding an extension.